# How to get Guest ID Magento

Tags: magento, get

How does one get the Guest ID in Magento? I see it in administration under Customers>Guests but how can one print it on a page in the front end?

I found this for regular customers:

```
<?php
echo Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();
?>
```

Comment: This answer can help to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048180/how-do-i-create-a-magento-session-outside-of-magento

Answer (score 5):

```
$visitorData = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getVisitorData();
echo $visitorData['visitor_id'];
```

Comment: This is not working for the first page load. Could you please tell me the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Mage::getModel('core/session')->getVisitorId();
```

good luck!

Comment: This does not work for me on enterprise ver. 1.13.0.2

Comment: @activeDev Try `zend_debug::dump(Mage::getModel('core/session')->getData())` (*this is just like var_dump*). now check what is the exact call to be made for getting guest id.